# How can I escape my numpad/keyboard for my 30 textfield inputs?

Tags: swift, xcode

I just implemented about 30 textfield inputs and after running my app I realized that I am not able to escape the numpad in anyway?? Has anyone figured out a simple solution to escape/remove the numbpad/keyboard?? I found the solution of adding a toolbar to the keyboard but that would require me to do that 30 times which doesn't sound efficient to me.

Comment: You could put one Done button in main interface. Or use scroll view, though that is less discoverable.

Comment: What does escape mean? you mean hiding/dismissing it?

Also you don't need to "do it 30 times", you can make a class, change that 30 something textfields to that class and viola, you've implemented for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
extension UITextField {

@IBInspectable var doneAccessory: Bool {

    get {
        return self.doneAccessory
    }
    set (hasDone) {
        if hasDone {
            addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
        }
    }
}

func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {

    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = .default
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))
    let items = [flexSpace, done]
    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
    self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}

@objc func doneButtonAction() {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
}


}
```

and add this single line to your text fields

```
textField.doneAccessory = true
```